# How to restart an application in task scheduler when it crashes using C# .net code

Tags: c#, scheduler

I have a windows form application for printing letters, it basically checks every 20 seconds in SQL Server for the letters request to print, if it finds any record it prints those letter. My application is working fine and I am using Timer control to run it every 20 seconds, its basically a one form application and I have disabled the form and assigned the application to task scheduler to run it daily.
Now I want to find out what will happen if my application Crashes, how can I restart it in task scheduler.

Thanks,

Mitz.

Comment: Why not change this to a windows service and set the settings in the os to restart on crash? (comes with every windows)

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not configuring it to run every 20 seconds in task scheduler instead of in the application itself? And obviously only running it once.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a service (New Project -> Windows Service) or you can use `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event and restart your binary from there.